# How to stop Numbers from beeping at me when I use the arrow keys?

Tags: keyboard, numbers

When I edit spreadsheets in Numbers, I often hold down the left or right arrow key to get to the far-left or far-right column of a table. Numbers always beeps at me when I do this. It seems to think it is an error to press keys that try to move outside the boundaries of a table, even though the keystrokes are from keyboard auto-repeat.

This is highly annoying. How do I stop Numbers from beeping at me all the time? I know I can mute the system volume or the default beep sound, but I like to listen to music, and the beeps in other programs are sometimes useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut for going to the last cell of a row: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>

The keyboard shortcut for going to the first cell of a row: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>

The keyboard shortcut for going to the last cell of a column: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>

The keyboard shortcut for going to the first cell of a column: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>

This will save holding the arrow key down repeat extending beyond the table bounds resulting in the annoying beeping/screen flash error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to resolve this directly, but here's a work-around for the problem of the beep being annoying:

Mute the default beep sound, and turn on "Flash the screen when an alert occurs" instead.  This is in System Preferences > Accessibility > Audio (in 10.8.3).

Comment: Well, I tried this, but unfortunately, I find the screen flash more annoying than the beep.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I have two ideas: 1) investigate writing an AppleScript to move to the far-left column, and arrange to call this via a keyboard shortcut (I don't know if this is possible, sorry, but it may be worth a look); 2) give feedback to Apple about the issue at http://www.apple.com/feedback/numbers.html